# Why won't ORDER BY work?

Tags: php, mysql, web, sql-order-by

I didn't write this code, it's from the Racetracker (http://sourceforge.net/projects/racetracker/), but I've been trying to make a couple modifications.

I'm trying to make a brief teams standings list, and thus limit it to 5 teams.  The teams standings page has "ORDER BY `SUM(driverpoints)`" in it, but it doesn't do anything (the page uses Javascript to manually sort the HTML table).  Furthermore, when I try to add a LIMIT 5, it similarly does nothing, it simply prints all the different teams.  Here's the relevant code (I removed a lot of repetitive ORs here, as there were 43 of the OR `drivername` = '$thenames[1]' qualifiers, they don't affect whether or not the ORDER BY and LIMIT parts work):

```
$total= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(driverpoints), SUM(events), SUM(firstplace),
        SUM(qual1stplace), SUM(lapsseason), SUM(lapsledseason), SUM(top5season),
        SUM(top10season), SUM(provisionals) 
    FROM `$whatseriestable` 
    WHERE `year` = $siteyear AND `drivername` = '$thenames[0]' 
        OR `drivername` = '$thenames[1]' 
    ORDER BY `SUM(driverpoints)` DESC LIMIT 5");
```

What is also puzzling is that ORDER BY and LIMIT work fine in the drivers standings summary:

```
$stn= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$whatseriestable` 
    WHERE `year` = $siteyear 
    ORDER BY `driverpoints` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Why doesn't this work with the teams standings?

Comment: You're selecting nothing but aggregated fields with no `group by` clause... how could mysql produce more rows since you've not told it anything about how to split the results into appropriate groups? The limit is pointless in your query, because it is impossible for the query to produce anything other than exactly **ONE** row.

Comment: @juergen: you can order by derived fields, OP's problem is that he hasn't grouped, so there's only one row of results, EVER.

Comment: Yes, your comment is actually much more accurate.

Comment: As a side point, if you have lots of `OR drivername =` bits, why not use an `drivername IN (blah)`?

Comment: Ok, so it would make sense to group by the team name, but unfortunately the team name is for some reason stored in a different table.  Thus, I'm not sure how to go about grouping the results.  As a side point, as I mentioned, I did not write this code, and since a. I am not that experienced with SQL, and b. I'm not publishing this site, I'm not too concerned at the moment with the redundant OR bits.

Answer (score 2):

Its probably all just your WHERE clause... AND's take a precidence over the or so

```
WHERE 
       `year` = $siteyear 
   AND `drivername` = '$thenames[0]' 
    OR `drivername` = '$thenames[1]'
```

Is being interpreted as

```
WHERE 
     ( year condition and first driver condition ) 
  OR ( second driver )
```

I think what you mean is

```
WHERE 
     ( year condition )
 and ( first driver condition OR second driver )
```

Wrap your driver conditions in ( ) parens.